# Is there a way to run some client side code after XSLT Sharepoint List View WebPart Ajax refresh

Tags: ajax, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint XSLT List View Web Part. I have my XSL to format the list items in html ul list. I call some client side script in jquery ready function to make the ul>li items to scroll.

I would like to use the built in Ajax refresh of the web part. But the problem is when the web part refreshes my rotate script call does not work any more. I researched on using jquery live() but looks like I can't use live with load() event.

Is there any way to reload my scripts upon Sharepoint Ajax refresh?

Comment: Has anyone found solution to this?